# Javascript not work after firing Updatepanel in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, updatepanel

My website's template is based on bootstrap and in the nav menu, I used the below code for some effects!

```
$('.productbar .dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).fadeIn(300);
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).animate({ top: "45px" }, 300);
    });

    $('.productbar .dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).fadeOut(300);
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).animate({ top: "55px" }, 300);
        $(this).find('.sub-menu').hide();
        $(this).find('.left-caret').addClass("right-caret").removeClass("left-caret");
    });
```

After firing the action button, updatepanel will fire and after this, the menu effect doesn't work!

What is the solution?

Comment: so what is the issue? please mention clearly. insufficient and unclear data :(

Comment: Sorry my friend, post edited :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This occurs due to the `Partial Postback` using `UpdatePanel`.  The `Events` that you  subscribe for the controls are rendered partially hence the events looses. To overcome this situation you need to rebind the control events.

This is a common problem caused by mixing the conventional ASP.Net Ajax and jQuery events. When you do the partial postback, the **DOM is recreated and the jQuery events are lost.**

**Example:**

```
<script type="text/javscript">
    // bind the events (jQuery way)
        $(document).ready(function() {
            bindEvents();   
        });
    
        // attach the event binding function to every partial update
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function(evt, args) {
            bindEvents();
        });
<script/>
```

**[Read More about PageRequest Manager on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397432%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**

Here `bindEvents()` method contains all the script that you need to reload again after Partial Page Postback.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same problem. I got help from this link. [Execute JavaScript when an UpdatePanel is updated](https://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/code-snippets/execute-javascript-when-an-updatepanel-is-updated/)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
                        upPanel,
                        this.GetType(),
                        "MyAction",
                        "doMyAction();",
                        true);
}
```

1. The first parameter is the UpdatePanel
2. The second parameter is a type parameter
3. The third parameter, “MyAction”, is a key to identify the script.
4. script itself.
5. The final parameter is a flag to indicate whether the ScriptManager should wrap your code in script tags.

Comment: Thanks for you and for Mr. Adam Pope who wrote the original blog

Comment: I dont know why its written inside the Page_Load function, It can be any function and when that is called then it will trigger the said script. In my case I needed to show a toast, here is my updated code: private void DisplayMessagePanel(string message = "")
        {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
                SCPanel,
                this.GetType(), "ShowSuccessMessage", "ShowSuccessMessage('" +  message.Replace('\'', ' ') + "');", true);
        }

Answer (score 1):

If the above does not work, this should reload the events on any postback (partial or full).

Wrap your entire jquery DOM ready event function in the following:

```
function pageLoad() {

    $(document).ready(function () {
        
        //jquery code and events, event binding.. etc..

    }); }
```

This can be helpful if you have many asp:update panels..