# anchor tag popup not working inside the update panel

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

When I use the href popup inside Update panel it does not fire click event but outside the update panel, it works. I'm using jquery for a popup.
see my code here

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>

   <asp:Panel ID="personal_panel" runat="server">
     <table>
 <tr class="reason">
   <td>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txt_reasons" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
  </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>
    <asp:ImageButton class="back-img" ID="imgbtn_back" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/back-back.png" OnClick="imgbtn_back_Click" onClientclick="submit_hidden()"  />
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
  <p id="Div1"  style="margin-top: -120px;height: 100px;">
 <a id="popupsubmit" class="trigger_popup_fricc1">Submit</a></p>
                    </asp:Panel>

</ContentTemplate>

 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here My Jquery code for popup

```
                       <script>
            $(window).load(function () {
                $(".trigger_popup_fricc1").click(function () {
                    $('.hover_bkgr_fricc1').show();
                });
                $('.hover_bkgr_fricc1').click(function () {
                    $('.hover_bkgr_fricc1').hide();
                });
                $('.popupCloseButton').click(function () {
                    $('.hover_bkgr_fricc1').hide();
                });
               });

</script>
```

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202349/javascript-not-work-after-firing-updatepanel-in-asp-net

Comment: @George human, I tried but still not working

Comment: Try using postback trigger. Please refer this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075538/button-click-not-working-inside-update-panel

Comment: @bharadhi, I already used postback trigger for anchor tag and given runat server also .it does not fire the click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using postback trigger. Please refer this link.

[Button click not working inside update panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075538/button-click-not-working-inside-update-panel)

I hope it's helpful.

Comment: I want to use postback trigger for anchor if I use that still not working.

Comment: Maybe DOM is refreshed?! Is your script written at the end, above </body> tag?

Comment: @ Bharadhi Kugarajah , yes at the end above body tag